# Handoff not working between watchOS and iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-watch

I want to open my iPhone app from apple watch button click. I am using below code to achieve this,

In my constant file,

```
let sharedUserActivityType = "com.mycompanyname.myappname.openApp"
let sharedIdentifierKey = "identifier"
```

In my watch App controller : On button click,

```
updateUserActivity(sharedUserActivityType, userInfo: [sharedIdentifierKey : 123456], webpageURL: nil)
```

In my iPhone AppDelegate,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]!) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if (userActivity.activityType == sharedUserActivityType) {
        if let userInfo = userActivity.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject] {
            if let identifier = userInfo[sharedIdentifierKey] as? Int {
                //Do something
                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Handoff", message: "Handoff has been triggered for identifier \(identifier)" , delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Thanks for the info!")
                alert.show()
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Make below change in iPhone's plist file,

[image]

But I am not able to open my iPhone app using above code. Also somewhere in many SO links I found this method `openParentApplication:`. But this method is also not available now.

Anyone, please suggest any working solution.